# Using Google Maps API MarkerClusterer on custon icons?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, cluster-computing, markerclusterer

So I have a list of baseball teams I want to map that each have a custom icon and text window. Since my primary zoom level is at 4, most of the icons, especially in the northeast are very congested.

part of the code is below, sorry for the length. It's what I know to do right now. Had tried adding the markercluster variable, but wasn't sure how to add each team into it, that or make multiple clusters based on the teams I am having issues with.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<style type="text/css">
  html { height: 100% }
  body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
  #map-canvas { height: 100% }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBblZOVoLgeHeWlv_zt5dR6dlQbRHMUPKo&sensor=true">
 </script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(39.8282, -98.5795),
      zoom: 4
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
        mapOptions);



   var padres = 'http://s7d2.scene7.com/is/image/Fathead/lgo_mlb_san_diego_padres?layer=comp&fit=constrain&hei=50&wid=200&fmt=png-alpha&qlt=95,0&op_sharpen=1&resMode=bicub&op_usm=0.0,0.0,0,0&iccEmbed=0';
   var padresLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(32.7073, -117.1566);
   var padresmarker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: padresLatLng,
  map: map,
  icon: padres,
  title: 'San Diego Padres'
     }); 
var padresString =  '<div id="content">'+
  '<div id="siteNotice">'+
  '</div>'+
  '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">San Diego Padres</h1>'+
  '<div id="bodyContent">'+
  '</div>'+
  '</div>';
var padreswindow= new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  content: padresString
 });
google.maps.event.addListener(padresmarker, 'click', function() {
padreswindow.open(map, padresmarker);
 });

    var dodgers = 'http://i.cdn.turner.com/si/.element/img/4.0/global/baseball/mlb/logos/dodgers_50.png';
   var dodgersLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(34.0736, -118.2400);
   var dodgersmarker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: dodgersLatLng,
  map: map,
  icon: dodgers,
  title: 'Los Angeles Dodgers'
 }); 
var dodgersString =  '<div id="content">'+
  '<div id="siteNotice">'+
  '</div>'+
  '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Los Angeles Dodgers</h1>'+
  '<div id="bodyContent">'+
  '</div>'+
  '</div>';
var dodgerswindow= new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  content: dodgersString
});
google.maps.event.addListener(dodgersmarker, 'click', function() {
dodgerswindow.open(map, dodgersmarker);
});
}
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map-canvas"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As minimum you have to include `markerclusterer.js` library and to add

```
var mc = new MarkerClusterer(map, [dodgersmarker, padresmarker]);
```

at the end of `initialize()` function. Marker Clusterer expects as parameters a map, an array of markers and options as optional parameters.

Comment: thanks for the help! I'll see what I can do later on. Should var mc include all markers? I was wanting the markers to separate at a certain zoom level(8/9/10)

Comment: You can include all markers at once or add them later. For separation of markers: you will have to play with options `maxZoom` and `gridSize`

Comment: would     maxZoom or    gridSize be implemented in the var mc line?

Comment: Yes, it's 3rd optional argument like `{maxZoom: zoom, gridSize: size}` with your values for zoom and size.

Comment: Thanks. Haven't had the chance to mess with it yet, but hopefully I can get this working over the weekend

Comment: so the map opens fine when I add markerclusterer.js, but does not work when I add     `var mc1 = new MarkerCluster(map, [arizonamarker, padresmarker, dodgersmarker], {maxZoom: 7});` after var map

Comment: and for some reason, this doesn't do anything on my map:      `function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(39.8282, -98.5795),
          zoom: 4
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
            mapOptions);
var mcOptions = {gridSize: 50, maxZoom: 4};
var markers1 = [angelsmarker, dodgersmarker, padresmarker];
var mc1 = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers1, mcOptions);`

Comment: problem solved!!!!!! put the markers options after the markers were made in the code :) thanks for the help @anto jurković